# JavaScript If/Else and Comparison/Relational Operators

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

Here's my challenge:

> - Complete the `canIGet` function. This function should:
>
>   - take two arguments:
>
>     - 'item' should represent what the user wants to buy
>     - 'money' should represent how many dollars a user has
>     - return 'true' if a user can afford a given item according to the price chart below, false otherwise:
>
>       - 'MacBook Air' - $999
>       - 'MacBook Pro' - $1299
>       - 'Mac Pro' - $2499
>       - 'Apple Sticker' - $1
>     - return 'false' if the 'item' is not in the above list apple products

(Rather than returning true/false I am logging to console)

I would appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
var canIGet = function(item, money){
    if ((money >= 2499) && (item == "Mac Pro" || "Macbook Pro" || "Macbook Air" || "Apple sticker")){
        console.log("You can afford a Mac Pro");
    }
    else if ((2499 > money) && (money >= 1299) && (item == "Macbook Pro" || "Macbook Air" || "Apple sticker")){
        console.log("You can afford a Macbook Pro");
    }
    else if ((1299 > money) && (money >= 999) && (item == "Macbook Air" || "Apple sticker")){
        console.log("You can afford a Macbook Air");
    }
    else if ((999 > money) && (money >= 1) && (item == "Apple sticker")){
        console.log("You can afford a Apple sticker");
    } else {
        console.log("Get a job!");
    }
};
canIGet("Mac Pro", 1500);
```

Comment: *"I would appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong."* What makes you think your are doing something wrong? Is there a problem with your code? What is it?

Comment: To check our answers there is a mocha test. Even after fixing as Marc B suggested in his Answer, there are still problems.

Comment: *"To check our answers there is a mocha test."* Uhm what? Who is "our" and where is the test? *"there are still problems"* We can't help you if you don't tell us about them.

Comment: I am enrolled in an online course. The way we check if our answers are correct is with unit testing (Mocha). After running the test all it tells me is \n canIGet returns the correct results for MacBook Air:   \n AssertionError: expected false to be true \n canIGet returns the correct results for MacBook Pro:   \n AssertionError: expected false to be true  \n canIGet returns correct results for Apple Sticker:  \n AssertionError: expected false to be true

Comment: Then you should probably update your question and explain what exactly doesn't work for which input.

Comment: Therein lies the problem, Felix. Because I'm so new to this, I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have to explain **why**, only **what**. If you just say your code "doesn't work", we have no idea what to look for. However, if you say: "The unit test for my code fails for input ABC with message XYZ", then we have at least a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Javascript (and most other languages):

```
(item == "Mac Pro" || "Macbook Pro" || "Macbook Air" || "Apple sticker")){
```

is not testing `item` against each of those strings. You're doing a boolean OR of strings, then comparing that `OR` result against item.

e.g. it's parsed/executed as

```
(item == true || true || true || true)
(item == true)
("Sticker" == true)
true
```

You have to write it as

```
if (item == 'Mac Pro') || (item == 'Macbook Pro') || etc...
```